# Prove that the fast exponentiation algorithm halts after $\lceil \log_2n \rceil+1$ steps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, solution-verification

This problem is adapted from chapter 6 of "Mathematics for Computer Science" (Lehman, Leighton, Meyers, 2018).

## Problem

> Consider the following fast exponentation algorithm.
>
> Given inputs $a\in\mathbb{R},b\in\mathbb{N}$, initialize registers $x,y,z$ to $a,1,b$ respectively, and repeat the following sequence of steps until termination:
>
> - if $z=0$ **return** $y$ and terminate
> - $r:=\text{remainder}(z,2)$
> - $z:=\text{quotient}(z,2)$
> - if $r=1$, then $y:=xy$
> - $x:=x^2$
>
> The behavior of this algorithm can be modelled with a state machine:
>
> 1. states := $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$,
> 2. start state := $(a,1,b)$,
> 3. transitions are defined by the following rule:
>
> $(x,y,z)\rightarrow \begin{cases} 
>       (x^2,y,\text{quotient}(z,2)) & \text{if }z\text{ is nonzero and even,} \\
>       (x^2,xy,\text{quotient}(z,2)) & \text{if }z\text{ is nonzero and odd.}
>    \end{cases}$

Prove that the fast exponentiation state machine will halt after $\lceil \log_2n \rceil+1$ transitions starting from any state where the value of $z$ is $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

## Solution attempt

Proof by strong induction.

**Induction hypothesis**: $P(n)$ := for any state $s=(x,y,z)$ where $z = n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, the fast exponentiation state machine will stop after $\lceil \log_2n \rceil+1$ transitions.

**Base case**: $P(1)$ is true, because, starting from any state where $z = 1$:

- the first transition will move to a state where $z = \text{quotient}(z, 2) = 0$
- since $z$ is now $0$, there are no further transitions.

  Therefore, there is only $1 = \lceil \log_2(1) \rceil+1$ transition.

**Inductive step**:

Assume that, for some $n \geq 1$, $P(k)$ is true for all $k \leq n$.

We want to show that $P(n+1)$ is true; that is, we want to show that, for any state $s=(x,y,z)$ where $z = n+1$, the fast exponentiation state machine will stop after $\lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil+1$ transitions.

Let $s$ be a state of the fast exponentiation state machine where $z = n + 1$.

Let $t$ be a state such that there is a transition from $s$ to $t$.

Applying such transition, the state $t$ will have

$z_t = \begin{cases} 
  (n+1)/2 & \text{if }n+1\text{ is even,} \\
  (n/2) & \text{if }n+1\text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}$

Since both possible values of $z_t$ ($(n+1)/2$ and $n/2$) are smaller than $n + 1$, the induction hypothesis can be applied for state $t$.

Let $T$ denote the number of transitions starting from $t$ after which the state machine will halt. Then, the number of transitions starting from $s$ will be 1 + $T$.

To find the value of $T$, there are two cases:

1. $n+1$ is even:

   $z_t = (n+1)/2$, so, by the induction hypothesis $P((n+1)/2)$, the state machine starting from state $t$ will stop after $\lceil \log_2((n+1)/2) \rceil + 1$ transitions.

   $T=\lceil \log_2((n+1)/2) \rceil + 1 = \lceil \log_2(n+1) - 1 \rceil + 1 = \lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil$
2. $n+1$ is odd:

   $z_t = n/2$, so, by the induction hypothesis $P(n/2)$, the state machine starting from state $t$ will stop after $\lceil \log_2(n/2) \rceil+1$ transitions.

   $T=\lceil \log_2(n/2) \rceil+1 = \lceil \log_2n - 1 \rceil+1 = \lceil \log_2n \rceil$

Since $\lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil \gt \lceil log_2n \rceil$, then, in both cases above, $T$ is at most $\lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil$.

Therefore, the number of steps starting from state $s$ is at most $1 + \lceil \log_2(n+1) \rceil$.

This proves $P(n+1)$.

Therefore, by strong induction, $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq 1$.

Can anyone please verify this solution attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, the parts of the algorithm that are relevant to discuss the number of steps are

---

Repeat the following sequence of steps until termination:

- if $z=0$ terminate
- $z:=\text{quotient}(z,2)$

---

But you can notice that

$$\text{quotient}(\text{quotient}(z_0,2),2)=\text{quotient}(z_0,2^2)$$ and more generally, by induction, the effect of $k$ iterations is

$$z:=\text{quotient}(z_0,2^k).$$

So $z$ is nonzero as long as

$$2^k\le z_0,$$ and becomes zero when

$$2^{k-1}\le z_0<2^k$$ or

$$k-1\le\log_2z_0<k.$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you find any problem in the solution that I presented in the question, even though it is much less compact than the one you posted?

Comment: @favq: honestly, it is too much verification work.